# Pass JSON data in a http GET request to a REST service

Tags: c#, rest, django-rest-framework, httprequest

Using the following command:

```
curl -v -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {'"mode":"0"'} http://host.domain.abc.com:23423/api/start-trial-api/
```

I am able to send the JSON data to web request and get the response back.
How can I do the same in C#?

I am able to POST data to the other service and get the response but don't understand how to send the data to GET request.
I tried searching on google and stackoverflow for the same in C#, but did not find anything.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Please leave a comment so it can be improved.

Comment: If it's truly a REST service would you pass a parameter or build into the uri. somedomain/api/0

Comment: Hey The King, did you find a solution? Could you post it here? I got the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code - Make sure the request method is set to "GET"

```
        string url = "";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        var webResponse = request.GetResponse();

        using (var s = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(s, true))
            {
               string jsonString = textReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This code does not have the data that needs to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of `abstractions` here, but hopefully will give a rough guide on how to connect to a service in `C#`

**The Interface**

```
public interface IShopifyAPIGateway
{
   HttpResponseMessage Get(string path);
}
```

**Shopify API Gateway**, which `instatiates` `HTTPClient()`

```
public sealed class ShopifyAPIGateway : IShopifyAPIGateway
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            private Identity _identity;
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            private HttpClient _httpClient;
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            public ShopifyAPIGateway(Identity
                identity)
            {
                _identity = identity;
                _httpClient = new HttpClient(ClientHandler());
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public HttpResponseMessage Get(string path)
            {
                try
                {
                    var response =  Connect().GetAsync(path).Result;
                    return response;
                }
                catch (CustomHttpResponseException ex)
                {
                    new Email().SendEmail(_identity.ClientName, "Http Response Error - Shopify API Module",
                     "Http Response Error - Shopify API Module: " + ex.Message,
                     "error@retain.me");

                    throw new CustomHttpResponseException(ex.Message);
                }

            }
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private HttpClient Connect()
            {
                try
                {
                    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_identity.APIURL);
                    return _httpClient;
                }
                catch (CustomHttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    throw new CustomHttpRequestException(ex.Message);
                }

            }
            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="userKey"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private HttpClientHandler ClientHandler()
            {
                try
                {
                    return new HttpClientHandler()
                    {
                        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_identity.APIKey,
                                                            _identity.Password),
                        PreAuthenticate = true
                    };
                }
                catch (CustomClientHandlerException ex)
                {    
                    throw new CustomClientHandlerException(ex.Message);   
                }
            }
        }
```

**Generic repo** to return any `object(s)` where the response object matches `T`

```
public sealed class EntityRepository<T> : IEntityRepository<T>
    {
        private IShopifyAPIGateway _gateWay;
        public T Find(string path)
        {
            try
            {
                _gateWay = new ShopifyAPIGateway(_identity);
                var json = _gateWay.Get(path).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                T results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json.Result);

                return results;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException(ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
```

**Usage** return type must match the `Type` your passing and also the Type that's being returned in response.

```
private IEnumerable<Order> Orders()
{
   var entityRepo = new EntityRepository<Order>();
   return entityRepo.Find("somedomain/api/orders?mode=0", _identity);
}
```

Comment: I understand how to connect to a web service. I am also able to make a POST call to the service and get the response successfully. I just wanted to know how to send the JSON data in the GET request.

Comment: Apologies, I may have interpreted the Q wrong... you say the "other service". Is that a service you've built, is it web api. Please update more about your .net environment. When you say pass data up, you mean an Id? as generally (as you know) with GET requests, it's getting typically by Id.